# Spring boot jooq dao trouble

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, dao, jooq

I'm new to Java and Spring and I am doing my first rest service. I've encountered a problem to which I cannot find an answer.

I generated entities using Jooq with pojos and daos

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.6</version>
            <executions>
            ...
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring</url>
                    <user>postgres</user>
                    <password>${env.PGPASSWORD}</password>
                </jdbc>
                <generator>
                    <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>
                    <database>
                     ...
                    </database>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>com.example.otrtesttask.jooq</packageName>
                        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                    </target>
                    <generate>
                        <pojos>true</pojos>
                        <daos>true</daos>
                        <records>true</records>
                    </generate>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

My database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE branch(id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE position(id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(30));

CREATE TABLE employee
(
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    manager_id  INTEGER REFERENCES employee (id),
    position_id INTEGER REFERENCES position (id) NOT NULL,
    full_name   VARCHAR(50)                      NOT NULL,
    branch_id   INTEGER REFERENCES branch (id)   NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE task
(
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    priority    SMALLINT                     NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(200)                 NOT NULL,
    employee_id INT REFERENCES employee (id) NOT NULL);
```

Then I made Controller that calls Service that calls Repository to invoke CRUD operations.
And it works perfectly fine, but I want to get position title along with id, etc. So I made a DTO:

```
@Data
public class EmployeeDto {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer managerId;
    private Integer positionId;
    private String fullName;
    private Integer branchId;
    private Employee manager;
    private Position position;
    private Branch branch;
}
```

After that I made a mapper that converts Employee to EmplyeeDto. I've been told that the best way to get nested data (like position title) is to use DAO fetchOnyById function.

```
@Service
public class MappingUtils {
    EmployeeDao employeeDao = new EmployeeDao();
    PositionDao positionDao = new PositionDao();
    BranchDao branchDao = new BranchDao();

    public EmployeeDto mapToEmployeeDto(Employee employee) {
        EmployeeDto dto = new EmployeeDto();

        dto.setId(employee.getId());
        dto.setBranchId(employee.getBranchId());
        dto.setPositionId(employee.getPositionId());
        dto.setFullName(employee.getFullName());
        dto.setManagerId(employee.getManagerId());

        dto.setManager(employeeDao.fetchOneById(employee.getManagerId()));
        dto.setPosition(positionDao.fetchOneById(employee.getPositionId()));
        dto.setBranch(branchDao.fetchOneById(employee.getBranchId()));
        return dto;
    }
```

And I map entities inside Repository like this:

```
   @Repository
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class EmployeeRepository {
        @Autowired
        private final DSLContext dsl;
        private final MappingUtils mappingUtils;
        public List<EmployeeDto> findAll(Condition condition) {
            return dsl.selectFrom(Tables.EMPLOYEE)
                    .where(condition)
                    .fetchInto(Employee.class)
                    .stream().map(mappingUtils::mapToEmployeeDto)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

And it works fine until it gets to the dao fetch function. It throws an exception `org.jooq.exception.DetachedException: Cannot execute query. No JDBC Connection configured`.
Once I remove the dao functions the get query returns nice response with manager, position and branch set to null.

What am I doing wrong here? And how to provide necessary connection?

==UPD==
My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=${PGPASSWORD}
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase/changelog.sql
```

Comment: How did you configure your Spring Boot `application.properties` file, or similar?

Comment: Added `application.properties` to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your DAO classes aren't attached to a jOOQ `Configuration`. You just created them like this:

```java
EmployeeDao employeeDao = new EmployeeDao();
```

But you have to create them like this:

```java
EmployeeDao employeeDao = new EmployeeDao(configuration);
```

You can also [configure the code generator to generate Spring annotations](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-generate/codegen-generate-annotations/) and then inject the DAOs to your class. The configuration would be:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <generate>
      <springAnnotations>true</springAnnotations>
      <!-- ... -->
```

And then:

```java
@Service
public class MappingUtils {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;
    @Autowired
    PositionDao positionDao;
    @Autowired
    BranchDao branchDao;
    // ...
```

Comment: That worked flawlessly! Tnaks so much!